# Scala implicit parameters are marked as unused by the compiler

Tags: scala

In scala when compiling with `-Ywarn-unused`, implicit parameters are marked as never used even if they are used in implicit scope.

For example

```scala
class MyClass(implicit: ec: ExecutionContext) {
  def fun = Future.successful("hi").map(_.length)
}
```

This is problematic when running with `-Xfatal-warnings` as well.

Is there a way to hint to the compiler that these parameters are in fact used? If not, is there another way to ensure code won't compile with unused parameters and declarations?

Comment: Not every method from `Future` need `ExecutionContext`. Try replacing `successful` with `Future.apply`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. Go ahead and submit that as an answer!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`-Ywarn-macros:after`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html) **flag** too. It basically tells the compiler to make the unused checks *after* macro expansion, that usually solve the problem of unused implicits.